# Run specific python behave test

Tags: python-behave

I have `.feature` file with 2 scenarios:

```
Scenario: flying to space
Scenario: flying to space fast
```

If I want to execute only `flying to space` I'm running `python -m behave --name "flying to space"` but it will also execute the `flying to space fast` scenario.

How can I ran only the first scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I've read the `behave --help` again and noticed that you can actually specify a file name and line number in the format `python -m behave .\features\something.feature:13` to run scenario in line 13, or the closest scenario defined above line 13.

This allows to run a specific scenario without even involve the scenario name.

Answer (score 0):

tag your scenario with `wip` for ex. then run `behave --tags=wip` this will run just the scenarios tagged @wip
check: https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

The `--name` flag takes a regular expression - you can force an exact match with:

```
python -m behave --name "^flying to space$"
```

(`^` matches the start of the text, `$` matches the end)